# Mac, list the usb port name that my device is connected to

Tags: macos, command-line, usb, ls

I currently need to figure out what is the name of the port that my usb device is connected to. More specifically, **I need to know what to put for the following**[image]

I am using a Mac, and I have run the command line `system_profiler SPUSBDataType`, and it gave me the following. **The device of my interest is the second one:  CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Controller.** But how do I figure out what the serial port that this device is connected to? I need it for my first image.

```
USB:

    USB 3.0 Bus:

      Host Controller Driver: AppleUSBXHCIWPT
      PCI Device ID: 0x9cb1 
      PCI Revision ID: 0x0003 
      PCI Vendor ID: 0x8086 

        Bluetooth USB Host Controller:

          Product ID: 0x8290
          Vendor ID: 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.)
          Version: 1.46
          Speed: Up to 12 Mb/sec
          Manufacturer: Broadcom Corp.
          Location ID: 0x14300000 / 2
          Current Available (mA): 500
          Current Required (mA): 0
          Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
          Built-In: Yes

        CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Controller:

          Product ID: 0xea60
          Vendor ID: 0x10c4  (Silicon Laboratories, Inc.)
          Version: 1.00
          Serial Number: 0001
          Speed: Up to 12 Mb/sec
          Manufacturer: Silicon Labs
          Location ID: 0x14200000 / 9
          Current Available (mA): 500
          Current Required (mA): 100
          Extra Operating Current (mA): 0

        Microsoft USB Optical Mouse:

          Product ID: 0x00cb
          Vendor ID: 0x045e  (Microsoft Corporation)
          Version: 1.00
          Speed: Up to 1.5 Mb/sec
          Manufacturer: PixArt
          Location ID: 0x14100000 / 4
          Current Available (mA): 500
          Current Required (mA): 100
          Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
```

---

## update: I ran `df` command, and it gave me the following:

```
Filesystem    512-blocks     Used Available Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1     974716928 77014080 897190848     8%  754757 4294212522    0%   /
devfs                380      380         0   100%     660          0  100%   /dev
map -hosts             0        0         0   100%       0          0  100%   /net
map auto_home          0        0         0   100%       0          0  100%   /home
map -fstab             0        0         0   100%       0          0  100%   /Network/Servers
/dev/disk2s1      202248   198912      3336    99%      12 4294967267    0%   /Volumes/VirtualBox
/dev/disk3s1       81800    67720     14080    83%     121 4294967158    0%   /Volumes/Sublime Text
/dev/disk5s1     1228720   386824    841896    32%     370 4294966909    0%   /Volumes/Etcher
```

Comment: Also see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/242104/is-there-a-way-to-access-a-usb-serial-port-by-the-device-id-not-by-the-tty-po

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try running `ls /dev/tty*` in a Terminal before and after plugging your device into USB.  If there is an entry that only appears when the USB device is plugged in, that would be the entry corresponding to the device.

Answer (score 2):

On a MacBook do this:

```
# device not plugged in
ls /dev/ > notPluggedIn.txt

# device plugged in
ls /dev/ > pluggedIn.txt

# find what you plugged in
diff notPluggedIn.txt pluggedIn.txt
```